# Hide specific shipping method depending on day time in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, time, shipping-method

I'm looking to create a PHP code snippet that I would add to my functions.php file but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Someone asked the same question 2 years ago ([Woocommerce - disable certain shipping methods based on time of day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51424968/woocommerce-disable-certain-shipping-methods-based-on-time-of-day)) but finally opted for a plugin that does that. I already use add-ons for detailed delivery options and I don't want to change or add another one just for this simple function if something can be done easily with php.

So I'm looking to disable a shipping method if the client order after 11AM (website time zone).

So I have this code for now :

```
if (date('H') > 11) { 
     $shippingmethod1.disable();
}
```

Can someone give me the proper code to make it work?

[image: Printscreen 1]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quiet simple using `woocommerce_package_rates` filter hook.

Now you need to find out what is the shipping rate Id reference that you need to target. For that you will inspect the desired shipping method radio button *(`<input>` field)* with  your browser tools to get value as shown below:

[image]

Once you get it you will set that in the code below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_time', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_time( $rates, $package )
{
    // Set your default time zone (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    
    // Here set your shipping rate Id
    $shipping_rate_id = 'local_pickup:13';

    // When this shipping method is available and after 11 AM
    if ( array_key_exists( $shipping_rate_id, $rates ) && date('H') > 11 ) {
        unset($rates[$shipping_rate_id]); // remove it
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **Clearing shipping caches**:
>
> - You will need to empty your cart, to clear cached shipping data
> - Or In shipping settings, you can disable / save any shipping method, then enable back / save.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help! It seems to work but it seems that the time is related to the Universal Time, not my local time. So instead of 11AM (New York time), I have to set it up to 3PM (London Time) to make it work. The only problem is that in North America, we have daylight saving time. So on November 1, 2020, for example, time will forward one hour. I don't think this code will automatically adjust that. Is there a way to set the local time setup in the Wordpress setting instead?

[link](https://imgur.com/8N6h4DW)

Thank you!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisNicePlace - Just change the timezone on this line:

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

to 

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

This will also deal with daylight savings.